# How to check if a variable is a Magic Constant?

Tags: php, if-statement, constants

I don't find any way online or scratching through the PHP docs to do this.

Is there a friendly or light way check if a variable is a [Magic Constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) like `__FILE__` or `__DIR__`? Similar to [`is_callable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php)?

I want to check against the `$var` passed and run some if/else conditions on it.

Small example.

```
function test($var) {

    if ($var == 'string_value') {

        // Do this...

    }

    elseif (is_magic_constant($var)) {

        // Do this...

    }

    else {

        // Do this...

    }

}

test('string_value');
test(__FILE__);
```

Comment: What's the purpose of it, though? I don't quite understand the usage of it, why would you need to know if its a magic constant? But as far as I know, there isn't a function to check that.

Comment: This doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `test(__FILE__);`, `__FILE__` is immediately expanded so that your `test()` function receives a string of the full file path.

If you call `test('__FILE__');` it still receives a string, but then that string will be `"__FILE__"` and you can run that through `defined($var);` to see if it's a known constant.

There is no way to check if it's a *magic* constant. So you cannot distinguish them from the [reserved constants](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php), any of the constants defined by installed PHP extensions or from constants you `define()` yourself in your application. All you can check is whether the *string* in `$var` matches the name of a defined constant.